# Preventing web page embedded in iframe from overflowing horizontally

Tags: iframe, overflow

I'm trying to embed a web page from another site into an iframe. The source web page is wider than the web page it is being embedded into. Is there anyway to prevent the embedded web page from overflowing to the right in Internet Explorer? Chrome wraps all the text together into multiple lines so there is no horizontal scrolling, but IE9 seems to spread the text of the embedded web page onto single lines so that the iframe scrolls to the right for a long distance.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I ended up just putting IE9 into IE8 Standards mode: 
    `meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/`